# Finding the normal vector of a surface (Flux of a vector field n*dS expression)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This problem is practice for a final exam.

Let S be the closed surface whose bottom face B is the unit disc in the $xy$-plane and whose upper surface U is the paraboloid $ z = 1 − x^2 − y^2 , z \geq 0 $. Find the flux of $ F = <x, y, z> $. across U by setting up a surface integral for the flux and evaluating the resulting double integral.

I need to calculate $ \int \int  F \cdot n dS $ on U, where F is a vector field, n is the general normal vector on the surface ($ z = 1 - x^2 - y^2 $) and dS is a surface differential. I'm not sure how to go about calculating the normal vector.

I thought that the formula was just $ || \frac{dz}{dx} x \frac{dz}{dy} || $, but the answer gives $ <2x, 2y, 1>dxdy $ directly for $ n dS $.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Parametrize your surface first. For starters, I would try $(x,y, 1 - x^2 - y^2)$. There should be a formula lurking somewhere in your book so you wouldn't need to do the computation based on my parametrization.